How to Scrape ETH Blockchain
I am starting a new project in which I would like to scrape wallet addresses from the ethereum blockchain and their transaction data to see how profitable they are.
What tools can you guys recommend I start out using? Ex: IDE, language, how to actually scrape the blockchain, etc.
I have looked into running my own node using geth but am open to any other suggestions.
Thanks

Blockchain data does not need to be scraped, as all data is publicly available to download locally. Scraping by definition means that you would extract the data from web user interface which does not make any sense in this context.

Run Ethereum node locally
You can pull all data from your local Ethereum node database over JSON-RPC

You can for example use Web3.py Python library to pull out the data.
If you have not done blockchain programming before, it is recommended you take any of online courses first, because you cannot work on a subject where you do not have basic required knowledge.

I've made scrapers for the BNB, Matic, and Optimism blockchains just using python to do exactly what you're talking about.
